# Confused about importing modules.Modules not being import from being in same folder||?

Tags: python, import, module, pygame

I have a root folder 'GAME'
here's the tree

1. GAME/main.py
2. GAME/scripts/level0.py
3. GAME/scripts/player.py

In main.py I try to import the module level0. (which is imported.)

```
import pygame as pg
import sys
from pygame.locals import *
from scripts.level0 import *

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        pg.init()
        self.WINDOW_SIZE = (800,600)
        self.screen = pg.display.set_mode(self.WINDOW_SIZE,0,32)
        self.display = pg.Surface((480,360))
        pg.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16,2,512)  
        pg.display.set_caption('2d platformer action')
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()

    def new(self):
        #initialize variables here.
        g = Game()
        g.run()


    def update(self): # func called every frame
        pg.display.update()
        self.screen.blit(pg.transform.scale(self.display,self.WINDOW_SIZE),(0,0))
        self.clock.tick(60)

    def run(self):
        #main game loop
        self.playing = True
        while self.playing:
            level = Level()
            self.events()
            self.update()

    def events(self):
        for event in pg.event.get(): 
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pg.quit() 
                sys.exit()

        # Input Handling.
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_LEFT:
                    pass
                if event.key == K_RIGHT: 
                    pass

g = Game()
g.run()
```

And in level0.py

```
import pygame as pg
import sys
from pygame.locals import *
import player

class Level():
    def __init__(self):
        player = Player([100,100])
        player.render(g.display)
```

and player.py

```
import pygame as pg
import sys
from pygame.locals import *

class Player:
    def __init__(self, loc):
        self.loc = loc
        self.rect = self.get_rect()

    def render(self, surf):
        pg.draw.rect(surf, (255,255,255), self.rect)
        #surf.blit(self.img, (self.loc[0], self.loc[1]))

    def get_rect(self):
        return pg.Rect(self.loc[0], self.loc[1], 16, 16)

    def collision_test(self, rect):
        player_rect = self.get_rect()
        return player_rect.colliderect(rect)
```

The code main.py returns a error ModuleNotFoundError : 'player' module not found.
How do I fix it? I am pretty new to python and am not sure what's causing this.

Comment: why don't you keep all directly in `GAME` ?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: you may have to use `relative import` - ie `from . import player`

Comment: BTW: if you use `import player` or even `form . import player` then you still have use `player.Player()`. OR you have to use `from player import *` or relative with dot `from .player import *`

Comment: BTW: you have big problem with `g` in `Level`. You should send it as argument `def __init__(self, g)` and next `Level(self)`

Comment: Have a read of [how modules work in python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html).  If you `import player` then you'll have access to `Player` via `player.Player`.

Comment: I could put it directly in the GAME but then, the files become cluttered pretty soon and it would have been pretty difficult.

Comment: Sure, I will do that from now of putting a full error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use relative import using `.`

```
from . import player
```

or when you import all with `*`

```
from .player import *
```

---

You have also problem with `g` in `__init__` - it has no access to global `g` and you should rather send it as argumen

```
def __init__(self, g):
    player = Player([100,100])
    player.render(g.display)
```

and then execute it in `Game` with `self` which means instance of `Game` (like global `g`)

```
level = Level(self)
```

---

**scripts/level0.py**

```
import pygame as pg
import sys
from pygame.locals import *
from .player import *

class Level():

    def __init__(self, g):
        player = Player([100,100])
        player.render(g.display)
```

**main.py** - changed only `level = Level(self)`

**scripts/player.py** - without changes

Comment: Thanks. BTW I didn't put everything under GAME because it could get cluttered and difficult to organize.